# Unity Animator.Play how to transition to another animation at the same time

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

I currently have a sprite-based animation in which the player is running. I also have another animation where the player is running and holding a gun out and shooting, that plays at the exact same speed as the player running without the gun. The catch is, I'm using Animator.Play();

What I want is to start the player running with gun animation at the frame that the player running animation is currently at. For instance, if player running animation is at frame 20, and the player presses the shoot button, play the running with gun animation at frame 20.

Here is a rough example of my code so far:

```
if (!shooting) {animator.Play("PlayerRunning");}

if (shooting) {animator.Play("PlayerRunningShoot");}
```

I think the best example would be one of the NES megaman games' megaman shooting animataion, where when you press 'B' while running, his arm will immediately pop-up to shoot.

If any of this is confusing on what I am asking, let me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like actually using [Animation Layers](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AnimationLayers.html) would be way more interesting for you! I can not recreate a complete manual here - look into the docs and [this tutorial](https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/topics/animation/animator-controller-layers).

---

However, [Animator.Play](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.Play.html) 
has an optional parameter

> **normalizedTime**: The time offset between zero and one.

so you can start the new animation with the offset the current animation is at

you can use [`Animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo.html) to get the current state and the [`normalizedTime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimatorStateInfo-normalizedTime.html) the current clip is at

and [`Animator.GetCurrentAnimatorClipInfo`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.GetCurrentAnimatorClipInfo.html) to get the information (e.g. length) of the clip.

And either reference your target clip (I would prefer that) or you can use [`Animator.runtimeAnimatorController`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator-runtimeAnimatorController.html) to get all `AnimationClip`s and than use [`LinQ FirstOrDefault`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=netframework-4.6) to find the one with the target name:

(typing this in on my smartphone so no warranties)

```c#
using System.Linq;

// ...

if (!shooting)
{
    // assuming layer 0
    var state = animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0);
    var clipInfo = animator.GetCurrentAnimatorClipInfo(0);

    // so the time you want to start is currentNormalizedTime * current.length / newClip.length
    // if your clips will always have the exact same length of course you can
    // simply use the currentNormalizedTime
    var currentNormalizedTime = state.normalizedTime;
    var currentRealtime = currentNormalizedTime * clipInfo[0].clip.length;

    var newClip = animator.runtimeAnimatorController.animationClips.FirstOrDefault(c => string.Equals(c.name, "PlayerRunning"));

    var newNormalizedTime = currentRealtime / newClip.length;

    // for some reason it seems you can not use the optional parameters as you usually would
    // like ("PlayerRunningShoot", normaizedTime = newNormalizedTime)
    animator.Play("PlayerRunning", -1, newNormalizedTime);
}

if (shooting)
{
    var state = animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0);
    var clipInfo = animator.GetCurrentAnimatorClipInfo(0);
    var currentNormalizedTime = state.normalizedTime;
    var currentRealtime = currentNormalizedTime * clipInfo[0].clip.length;

    var newClip = animator.runtimeAnimatorController.animationClips.FirstOrDefault(c => string.Equals(c.name, "PlayerRunning"));

    var newNormalizedTime = currentRealtime / newClip.length;

    animator.Play("PlayerRunningShoot", -1, newNormalizedTime);
}
```

---

You could also create a smooth transition on runtime using

[Animator.CrossFade](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.CrossFade.html) or [Animator.CrossFadeInFixedTime](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.CrossFadeInFixedTime.html)

```c#
if (!shooting) 
{
    // ...       

    // here the transition takes 0.25 % of the clip
    animator.CrossFade("PlayerRunning", 0.25f, -1, 0, newNormalizedTime);
}

if (shooting) 
{
    // ...

    // here the transition takes 0.25 seconds
    animator.CrossFadeInFixedTime("PlayerRunningShoot", 0.25f, -1, 0, newNormalizedTime);
}
```

Comment: I tested it out, but I keep getting errors. Thanks for answering anyway.

Comment: I'm only on a smartphone so I can't test it unfortunately ... where exactly do you get errors and what kind?

Comment: *Assets/scripts/PlayerController.cs(73,60): error CS1061: Type `UnityEngine.AnimatorClipInfo[]' does not contain a definition for `length' and no extension method `length' of type `UnityEngine.AnimatorClipInfo[]' could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?* AND *Assets/scripts/PlayerController.cs(74,69): error CS1061: Type `UnityEngine.AnimationClip[]' does not contain a definition for `FirstOrDefault' and no extension method `FirstOrDefault' of type `UnityEngine.AnimationClip[]' could be found. Are you missing `System.Linq' using directive?* Thts just 2 of em, but comnt spce lmted.

Comment: yeah sorry it has to be `clipInfo[0].clip.length` ... for the second as it says in the error you need to add `using System.Linq;` to the top of the script. But you should really have a look at AnimationLayers instead it would solve your issue immediately

Comment: I think you should wait until you are able to test it, since I have about eight different errors. Thanks for trying though!

Comment: Hey fixed compiler errors I could find now .. sorry I was a bit to quick this morning ^^

Comment: It works, but for some reason the animation is playing a lot slower.