# Problem with transition between animations

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, 2d, game-development

I am creating Unity 2D top down shooter, and I am having two animations: Reload, and Reload while running (it is reload but while speed > 0).

When character is reloading and running and then stop running in middle of animation, the state transist to Reload state, that is correct, but it starts this animation from beginning, is there any posible solution to transist to another animation state, and start it from the moment where last animation got interrupt(end)?

For example: my Reloading animation takes 2 seconds, same with Run-reload animation. My character keeps running and reloding, stops moving after 1s, so state is changed to reloading(without running) from 1 second(middle of animation) time?

Comment: Have a look at [Animation Layers](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AnimationLayers.html)! In general when asking about a code problem please add the code so we can work with it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unity Animator.Play how to transition to another animation at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54509267/unity-animator-play-how-to-transition-to-another-animation-at-the-same-time)

Comment: Thank you, my mistake was probably I should have try to animate things using code. At the moment I am using only animator UI. I found the answer in link you sent.